# C# - How to copy/create an object as a decendent

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, inheritance

This is easier to explain with an example.  Given these two classes:

```
public class MyClassA
{
    public String Property_A { get; set; }
    public String Property_B { get; set; }
    public String Property_C { get; set; }
    public String Property_D { get; set; }
    ...
    public String Property_Y { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassB: MyClassA
{
    public String Property_Z { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have fully created instance of MyClassA (with all properties from A - Y filled in).  Then I need to make an instance of MyClassB which is exactly the same as my instance of MyClassA but with Property_Z filled in (with a custom value of course).  How can I do this?

Doing this does not work (throws and Invalid Cast Exception):

```
MyClassB myInstanceB = (myClassB) myInstanceA;
myInstance.Property_Z = myCustomValue;
```

I have not needed to do anything like this since my C++ days and I am stumped.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE: I found a solution to my problem in how I create the instances.  It is below.  I did not mark it as the answer because it did not exactly fit my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instance you've created is a `MyClassA`.  That is its runtime type, not `MyClassB`.  You cannot cast a `MyClassA` instance to a `MyClassB` at runtime because `MyClassB` is a more specific type than `MyClassA`.

You need to create a brand-new instance of `MyClassB`.  One way to clean this up is to create a constructor that takes a `MyClassA`, e.g.

```
public class MyClassB : MyClassA
{
    public MyClassB(MyClassA a, string z)
    {
        this.PropertyA = a.PropertyA;
        this.PropertyB = a.PropertyB;
        // etc.
        this.PropertyZ = z;
    }

    public string PropertyZ { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did not say it, but I was hoping to avoid having to copy all of the items from one instance to another.

Comment: @Vaccano: If you find yourself having to do this all over the place then I would reconsider your design; however, if you desperately need to speed up the process then you could use Reflection or a Reflection-based mapper such as AutoMapper - just know that the time you save coding will be offset by increased execution times in the program (how much time depends on how often you do it).

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to slow down execution either.  I found a compromise (see my answer to this question) by changing how I setup myInstanceA to use type parameters.  I am not converting myInstanceA to a MyClassB like I hoped but it works.  (I will not set my answer as the "answer" because it does not quite match the question I asked.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflection to copy base class properties as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886/c-using-reflection-to-copy-base-class-properties).

```
 public void Update(MyObject o)
    {
        MyObject copyObject = ...
        Type type = o.GetType();
        while (type != null)
        {
            UpdateForType(type, o, copyObject);
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }


    private static void UpdateForType(Type type, MyObject source, MyObject destination)
    {
        FieldInfo[] myObjectFields = type.GetFields(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (FieldInfo fi in myObjectFields)
        {
            fi.SetValue(destination, fi.GetValue(source));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward answer:

```
public class MyClassA 
{ 
    public String Property_A { get; set; } 
    public String Property_B { get; set; } 
    public String Property_C { get; set; } 
    public String Property_D { get; set; } 
    ... 
    public String Property_Y { get; set; } 
} 

public class MyClassB: MyClassA 
{ 
    public MyClassB(MyClassA copy)
    {
        Property_A = copy.PropertyA;
        Property_B = copy.PropertyB;
        ...
    }
    public String Property_Z { get; set; } 
}
```

Use it like this:

```
MyClassB o = new MyClassB(instanceOfMyClassA);
o.Property_Z = whatever;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a free copy constructor. C# doesn't supply one (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28VS.80%29.aspx) but you can do it pretty easily with `Object.MemberwiseClone` or the BinaryFormatter serializer (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx). Take care to know if you want a shallow copy or deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an explicit or implicit cast from MyClassA to MyClassB and use the syntax you've provided.

```
public class MyClassB : MyClassA
{
    public String Property_Z { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator MyClassB(MyClassA a)
    {
        MyClassB b = new MyClassB();
        b.Property_A = a.Property_A;
        /* ... */
        b.Property_Y = a.Property_Y;
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

1. Create a base class that implements IClonable and has all the string properties A to D, and Z.
2. Create instance of this class for MyClassA.
3. Create instance of MyClassB by cloning MyClassA.
4. Set property Z in MyClassB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

I made my method that creates and sets up all the properties (A-Y) that uses type parameters.  It looks like this:

```
public T MakeAMyClass<T>(AnotherClass 
where T: MyClassA : new()
{
   T returnValue = new T();
   T.Property_A = somethingToSetFrom.MakeAPropertyA();
   // Fill in the rest of the properties
}
```

Because a type parameter can be a type that is descended from the constraint, I am able to pass in MyClassB objects and get them made the same way as myClassA.

Then I can make either one as needed.

```
MyClassA myInstanceA = MakeAMyClass<MyClassA>(somethingToSetFrom);
MyClassB myInstanceB = MakeAMyClass<MyClassB>(somethingToSetFrom);
myInstanceB.Property_Z = someotherValue;
```

The lets me avoid having to make a method to copy all the properties from MyClassA to MyClassB.