# Convert/Cast base type to Derived type

Tags: c#, .net

I am extending the existing .NET framework class by deriving it. How do I convert an object of base type to derived type?

```
public class Results { //Framework methods }

public class MyResults : Results { //Nothing here }

//I call the framework method

public static MyResults GetResults()
{
    Results results = new Results();
    //Results results = new MyResults(); //tried this as well.

    results = CallFrameworkMethod();

    return (MyResults)results; //Throws runtime exception
}
```

I understand that this happens as I am trying to cast a base type to a derived type and if derived type has additional properties, then the memory is not allocated. When I do add the additional properties, I don't care if they are initialized to null.

How do I do this without doing a manual copy?

Comment: Instead of extending the type can you just create an Extension method?

Comment: This is a good idea. With Extension methods, I can attach new methods. I can't really add additional properties/variables to the type.

Comment: That seems like a lot of work to avoid writing a simple copy constructor. I know in a lot of cases that isn't possible, but it seems like a possible solution in this case.

Comment: @overslacked -   How would the copy constructor look? Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.  If `results` doesn't refer to a `MyResults` (e.g. if `CallFrameworkMethod` returns a base `Results` instance), then casting won't make it so: you'll need to create a new `MyResults`, based on the existing non-`MyResults`.  Casting is about changing the compile-time type of the *reference*, not about changing the concrete type of the referenced object.

You can use tools such as Reflection or AutoMapper to help with the initialisation of the new `MyResults` object -- but a new `MyResults` object there must be, because you cannot tell a base `Results` object to become a `MyResults` object.

Comment: Is this have to do with variance/covariance? I am on .NET 4.0 and i know that they did something for variance/covariance. Any idea?

Comment: No, C# 4.0 variance is to do with when you're using base/derived types as type parameters for generic interfaces or delegates; and you don't have any generic interfaces or delegates here.  Your problem is more fundamental: it's about the concrete type of the object.  A Results object simply *is not* an instance of the MyResults type.  If CallFrameworkMethod returns an (actual) Results, references to that object *cannot* be cast to MyResults because the object *is not* a MyResults.  The only way around this is to change CallFrameworkMethod to return a MyResults, or to create a new MyResults.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>How about:</strike>

```
...
MyResults results  = new MyResults();
...
```

And you maybe also need to create a COnstructor in your `MyResults` class:

```
public class MyResults : Results
{
    public MyResults() : base() {}
}
```

What exactly means "nothing here"?

**EDIT**

```
 results = (CallFrameworkMethod() as MyResults);
```

It doesnt throw the exception, but if it would be useful for you - it depends on what you would like to do further...

Comment: "nothing here" as in literally nothing. For now, I have inherited from the base type with the intention of adding new properties in the future

Comment: I see. I Edited my answer - please check new solution.

Comment: @Gacek - Using the as keyword does not throw an exception but MyResult object is null although the CallFrameworkMethod returns a non null object.

Comment: Regarding your edit: if CallFrameworkMethod is returning a `Results` rather than a `MyResults` then your edit will just set `results` to null.  The cast still fails, but the `as` operator indicates this by returning null rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Is there in the Results class a constructor, that allows to create one object basing on other? Something like `Results(Results referenceObject)`? If so, you can implement similar constructor in your class (by deriving the original constructor) and then call it like that: `var results = new MyResults(CallFrameworkMethod());`

Comment: Unfortunately no. I looked at the Results implementation by the framework and it does not have this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Results results = new MyResults();
   ...

return (MyResults)results;
```

should work. If not, then the problem is somewhere alse.

Comment: No, because he then overwrites it with the return value of CallFrameworkMethod -- which is presumably returning something other than a MyResults, or the cast would succeed.

Comment: He makes an instance of the MyResult class and then calls the CallFrameworkMethod method which assigns to the results object some other instance which cannot be casted.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't avoid copying the content into a instance of the derived type.  Well, if you can change CallFrameworkMethod to be a generic method, and MyResults has a zero-argument constructor, then CallFrameworkMethod could create a new instance of your derived type directly, then use only the members of the parent type.

But probably you'll have to end up copying to a new object.  Remember that this copying code can certainly be reused in another method, you don't have to rewrite it everywhere you need it.

Comment: How would the copy constructor look? Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: C# doesn't have "copy constructors".  But you can certainly write a reusable method that accepts the base class and returns an instance of the derived class, with all the base class members copied.  Or were you asking about the generic idea?

Answer (score 1):

As earlier answers have said, you need to instantiate a new instance of MyResults then copy the properties over from your Results object. You asked what a "copy constructor" was - it is just a constructor that takes an object and uses it to populate the object being constructed. For example:

```
    public class Results
    {
        public string SampleProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string SampleProperty2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyResults : Results
    {
        public MyResults(Results results)
        {
            SampleProperty1 = results.SampleProperty1;
            SampleProperty2 = results.SampleProperty2;
        }
    }
```

A copy constructor is usually more convenient, readable and reusable than using code like this:

```
MyResults myResults = new MyResults
{
    SampleProperty1 = results.SampleProperty1,
    SampleProperty2 = results.SampleProperty2
};
```

If there are lots of properties and/or you are making lots of changes to the class you could use reflection (e.g. [C# Using Reflection to copy base class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886/c-using-reflection-to-copy-base-class-properties) ) or a tool such as AutoMapper ( http://automapper.codeplex.com ) to copy the properties. But often that can be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

To downcast an Object into its derived class(es), The Object must be *born* in it derived class.
For example:
I have a simple class called Shape
here is the code for Shape class

```
public class Shape{
     public void draw(){}
}
```

and then I have an other class named Circle as follows:

```
public class Circle:Shape{
      public void drawCircle(){}
}
```

Now if I create an object of Super class like

```
Shape noShape = new Shape();
```

And if try to downcast this `noShape` object to `Circle` object like this

```
Circle circle = (Circle) noShape;
```

it will generate an exception. This is because `circle` was never *born* as `Shape`
To perform this down-casting functionality, `noShape` must be *born* as `Circle` object. Which can be done as this:

```
Circle initialShape = new Circle();
```

Now you can simply upcast this `initialShape` object to `Shape` object. like this

```
Shape upcastedObject = initialShape;
```

Now you can Down-cast the object `upcastedObject` to its derived class like

```
Circle derivedCircle = (Circle) upcastedObject;
```

Now the `derivedCircle` object will behave like a `Circle` object. Because it was born as `Circle`. I am using the word **BORN** so keep this in mind.
The reason of doing so or the use-case of doing so is up to your requirement.