# "as" keyword in c# returns null data

Tags: c#, null

How do I get the *base class* data into the *child class* object when using *keyword* `as`. I tried the below code but it returns `null` data.

```
class BaseC
{
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}

class DerivedC: BaseC
{
    public int DerivedId { get; set; }
    public string DerivedName { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BaseC baseC = new BaseC();
        baseC.BaseId = 1;
        baseC.BaseName = "base class name ";
        var derivedC = baseC as DerivedC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the pure `Basec` you created is NOT a `DerivedC` so `as` will return `null since it can't be cast.  Downcasting is not allowed in C#.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A `BaseC` object is not always a `DerivedC` object (the other way around it is). You created just a `BaseC` object and not a `DerivedC` object. You try to do a narrowing cast (BaseC to DerivedC), while only a widening cast would work (DerivedC to BaseC).

Comment: Derived C inherits from BaseC and you want to treat BaseC as DeviedC... See the problem? Also, why using var? var is an undefined type use it in a linq for example

Comment: Have a look at [Is it really downcasting not possible? It is working fine for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956475/is-it-really-downcasting-not-possible-it-is-working-fine-for-me)

Comment: @user28470 `var` does not mean "undefined" - it means "let the compiler infer the type from the declaration".  It's perfectly fine to use outside of Linq.  In this case the compiler would use `DerivedC` as the _inferred_ type.

Comment: Yes, so var is undefined type it gets the type of what will it be used for

Comment: @user28470 No, "undefined" means "I can use it for anything", which is not what `var` means - so you can't say `var x = 1; x = "one";` because `x` is an `int`, not a `string` or "variant".

Answer (score 5):

That's right ***as*** behaivour:

Your code (simplified):

```
 BaseC baseC = new BaseC();

 // null: result is a BaseC instance and not DerivedC one
 DerivedC result = baseC as DerivedC;
```

Reversed code (probably, what you expected to see):

```
 BaseC baseC = new DerivedC(); // <- Now, DerivedC instance created

 // not null: result is in fact a DerivedC instance: new DerivedC()
 DerivedC result = baseC as DerivedC; 

 // not null: DerivedC is inherired from BaseC
 // and that's why any DerivedC instances are BaseC instances as well
 BaseC result2 = baseC as BaseC;
```

Answer (score 4):

This won't work. Replace `BaseC` with `Animal` and `DerivedC` with `Cow` and you'll see why.

The runtime cannot create a `Cow` from an instance of `Animal`, as there's information missing. This will work:

```
BaseC baseC = new DerivedC();
```

Because the instance *actually is* a `DerivedC`.

Comment: Wait, are you saying not every animal is a cow? :O

Answer (score 0):

`baseC` is not an instance of `DerivedC`, so the `as` operator will always return `null`.

It would work however, if you changed the first line of `Main` to this:

```
BaseC baseC = new DerivedC();
```

Answer (score 0):

As for a practical solution *(perhaps you were already doing this before you tried out the* `as` *keyword, but I figured I'd throw it out there):*

If all you have available is a base instance *(and you can't change that for some reason),* and you want to populate the derived instance, you might consider adding a constructor that accepts the base class as a parameter:

```
class DerivedC : BaseC
{
    public DerivedC() {}  // req'd so you can still create an instance without a BaseC

    public DerivedC(BaseC baseC)
    {
        BaseId = baseC.BaseId;
        BaseName = baseC.BaseName;
    }

    public int DerivedId { get; set; }
    public string DerivedName { get; set; }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var derivedC = new DerivedC(baseC);
```

At least that cuts down on code duplication, so you're not manually assigning values in multiple places.