# Clone XAML Element on Windows Phone 8 with all children

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, clone

Is it possible to clone arbitrary XAML elements and reuse them by renaming them and inserting them into the Page tree?

For example, cloning a PivotItem and changing and adding it to the Pivot (new one) with all its children.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564493/how-to-clone-uielement-in-winrt-xaml-c

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you :

```
this.ContentPanel.Children.Clear();
MyWindowsApplication.View.Page1 page1 = new MyWindowsApplication.View.Page1();
this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(page1);
```