# Make Copy of xaml child elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I am working on a windows phone app. I want to copy children of one canvas to other canvas. I can do it with the following code but the problem is I have to remove it from one canvas first. Code is:

```
private void add_template_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var childrenList = Template_canvas1.Children.Cast<UIElement>().ToArray();
    root.Children.Clear();
    foreach (var c in childrenList)
    {
        Template_canvas1.Children.Remove(c);
        root.Children.Add(c);
    }
}
```

I want to keep these elements on both the canvas. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to add the same `Template_canvas1.Children` to the `root` canvas, first make a copy of those `Children` and then add the copy to the `root` canvas.

```
public static T CloneXaml<T>(T source)
{
    string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(source);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xaml);
    XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr);
    return (T)XamlReader.Load(xr);
}
```

Then change your loop to:

```
foreach (var c in childrenList)
{
    var copy = CloneXaml(c);
    root.Children.Add(copy);
}
```

I haven't tested this code, so you may have to modify it a bit, but it should put you in the right direction.

Alternatively, you can probably use the code below which is copied from [Dr Herbie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16645061/3215948):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using System.Reflection;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace UIElementClone {
  public static class UIElementExtensions {
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source) where T : UIElement {
      T result; // Get the type 
      Type type = source.GetType(); // Create an instance 
      result = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as T;
      CopyProperties<T>(source, result, type);
      DeepCopyChildren<T>(source, result);
      return result;
    }

    private static void DeepCopyChildren<T>(T source, T result) where T : UIElement {
      // Deep copy children. 
      Panel sourcePanel = source as Panel;
      if (sourcePanel != null) {
        Panel resultPanel = result as Panel;
        if (resultPanel != null) {
          foreach (UIElement child in sourcePanel.Children) {
            // RECURSION! 
            UIElement childClone = DeepClone(child);
            resultPanel.Children.Add(childClone);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private static void CopyProperties<T>(T source, T result, Type type) where T : UIElement {
      // Copy all properties. 
      IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = type.GetRuntimeProperties();
      foreach (var property in properties) {
        if (property.Name != "Name") { // do not copy names or we cannot add the clone to the same parent as the original. 
          if ((property.CanWrite) && (property.CanRead)) {
            object sourceProperty = property.GetValue(source);
            UIElement element = sourceProperty as UIElement;
            if (element != null) {
              UIElement propertyClone = element.DeepClone();
              property.SetValue(result, propertyClone);
            }
            else {
              try {
                property.SetValue(result, sourceProperty);
              }
              catch (Exception ex) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If none of these worked for you, I'm afraid you'd have to implement your own serializer. It looks like [David Poll](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/) implemented a decent serlizer, so have a look. Using his serlizer is as simple as using the `XamlWriter`, then you can use the `XamlReader`:

```
public static T CloneXaml<T>(T source)
{
    UiXamlSerializer uxs = new UiXamlSerializer();
    string xaml = uxs.Serialize(source);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xaml);
    XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr);
    return (T)XamlReader.Load(xr);
}
```

To get this functionality, download his [Slab library](http://www.davidpoll.com/Download/SLaB/SLaBv0.11.zip), go to the "Binaries" folder and copy all the dlls that start with "SLaB.Utilities.Xaml.Serializer" to your project. There might be some other dlls required as dependency. He has example solution in the library if you like to look at the code an learn.

Comment: How do I make copy of those children?

Comment: Check [this post](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/), it has an implementation of Xaml serlializer which may do the trick for you.

Comment: See my updated answer. I've added a class that does the cloning.

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml not supported in windows phone sdk

Comment: OK, but have you checked [this post](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/) which I mentioned in my earlier comment? It should work on Windows Phone. I can added it to the answer if you like.

Comment: yes I have checked that post but XamlWriter doesn't work with windows phone, I dont know how to implement that. Can you please add it to the answer?

Comment: The post is exactly to solve that problem. He implemented a serializre that is probably even better than the `XamlWriter`. Just download his library and copy the dlls to your project. I updated my answer with the details as you requested.

Comment: It copies all attributes, but I'm not sure about the events. I think it does, but you will have to try it to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, with a precise description of what exactly you're trying to achieve, it's impossible to know for sure what the best answer would be.

That said, given that WPF already knows how to "clone" elements in a sense, through the use of data templates, your question really sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. That is, you only *think* you need to literally clone the elements already in your visual tree, when in fact what you *should* be doing is defining a view model that represents the data to be displayed for the element(s) to be "cloned", define a single data template that uses XAML to describe the visual elements that will display the data in the view model, and then simply apply the template as necessary wherever you want the visual elements to be "cloned".

I.e. they won't really be cloned. Instead, WPF will automatically populate a whole new sub-tree of visual elements exactly as you want them to be. Since the template allows you to completely define all aspects, there is no issue related to e.g. trying to get the event subscriptions hooked up, setting up bindings correctly, etc.

In your specific example (vague though it is), it sounds like you most likely want to use an `ItemsControl` element, in which the `ItemsPanel` is a `Canvas` object. You would then define a `DataTemplate` that represents a *single* item in the `ItemsPanel`; this template would be referenced either implicitly by setting its `DataType` property, or explicitly by setting the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` property. Then, instead of cloning anything, you just create an `ItemsControl` when you want a copy of your visual for the data.

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer after user's feedback that it is not working on Windows Phone

Complete final Windows Phone App can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lidjtp6385bfev0/PhoneApp1.rar?dl=0).

There are some API differences, for example instead of `pinfo.SetMethod` property we have to use `pinfo.GetSetMethod()` etc.

Secondly, I was unknowingly didn't check for `Name` property which must not be copied as otherwise we would be making another instance with same name.

Third, I posted for simple case of simple controls like `Button`, `TextBox`, `Rectangle` etc which do not contain children. If that is the case you have to go for recursive deep cloning to clone children too. As children could have more children and so on.

```
foreach (UIElement oldElem in Canvas1.Children)
{
    try
    {               
        Type t = oldElem.GetType();
        UIElement newElem = (UIElement)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        PropertyInfo[] info = t.GetProperties();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in info)
        {
            if (pinfo.Name == "Name") continue;
            try
            {
                if (pinfo.GetSetMethod() != null) // avoid read-only properties
                    pinfo.SetValue(newElem, pinfo.GetValue(oldElem, null),null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine((++i).ToString() + " : " + pinfo.ToString());
            }
        }

        Canvas.SetLeft(newElem, Canvas.GetLeft((oldElem)));
        Canvas.SetTop(newElem, Canvas.GetTop((oldElem)));

        Canvas2.Children.Add(newElem);
    }        
    catch (Exception ex)
    {         
    }
}
```

And if you are going for truly deep cloning then replace code in outer try block above with a simpler:

```
    foreach (UIElement oldElem in Canvas1.Children)
    {
        try
        {
            UIElement newElem = oldElem.DeepClone();
            Canvas2.Children.Add(newElem);

            Canvas.SetLeft(newElem, Canvas.GetLeft(oldElem));
            Canvas.SetTop(newElem, Canvas.GetTop(oldElem));                    
        }                
        catch (Exception ex){ }
    }
```

#### Old answer based on WPF only

Don't know about windows phone but in WPF this creates a fresh element and puts it in exactly same place in another canvas. Check if it fits your needs, else I will update it again.

```
foreach (UIElement oldElem in Canvas1.Children)
{
    Type t = oldElem.GetType();
    UIElement newElem = (UIElement)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    PropertyInfo[] info = t.GetProperties();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in info)
    {
        try
        {
            if (pinfo.SetMethod != null) // avoid read-only properties
                pinfo.SetValue(newElem, pinfo.GetValue(oldElem));                        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine((++i).ToString() + " : " + pinfo.ToString());
        }
    }

    Canvas.SetLeft(newElem, Canvas.GetLeft((oldElem)));
    Canvas.SetTop(newElem, Canvas.GetTop((oldElem)));
    Canvas.SetRight(newElem, Canvas.GetRight((oldElem)));
    Canvas.SetBottom(newElem, Canvas.GetBottom((oldElem)));

    Canvas2.Children.Add(newElem);
}
```

Comment: It throws an error "Element is already a member of another parent". This was the same error I had before. May be because xaml child can not be a child of more than 1 parent

Comment: I have checked before posting the answer. I dont knw what u r doing

Comment: create 2 canvas, put some controls in canvas1, above code will copy them and place them at exactly same place in another canvas.

Comment: Uploaded a sample https://www.dropbox.com/s/vttmmzf1j4wdvbp/WpfApplication1.rar?dl=0

Comment: Your answer works with xaml app but not with windows phone. It throws an error 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' on the line: pinfo.SetValue(newElem, pinfo.GetValue(oldElem));

Comment: @thewarri0r9 i am now developing a windows phone app. wait .

Comment: @thewarri0r9 Hi , I have solved your problem, see my updated solution and update back.

Comment: Thank you, for the solution. Code copies elements perfectly but doesn't copy their events which is most important for my project.

Comment: @thewarri0r9 will check

Comment: still waiting for your reply :/

Comment: @thewarri0r9 will update in next 2 hours, was helping another user