# Refactor method with if statements

Tags: c#, refactoring

How refactor this method fragment with using predicate?

```
SetUpdateUserValue(User updateUser, User user)
{
    if (user.FirstName != null)
        updateUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    if (user.LastName != null)
       updateUser.LastName = user.LastName;
}
```

Comment: `updateUser.FirstName != null ? user.FirstName : String.Empty` you want something similar to this?

Comment: I don't like many if statements. I need one method for all if statements

Answer (score 2):

From Your comments: `I don't like many if statements.`

if you want to reduce the number of statements you can use `null coalescing` operator

**Solution 1:** using  `null coalescing` operator

```
SetUpdateUserValue(User updateUser, User user)
{
    updateUser.FirstName = user.FirstName ?? updateUser.FirstName;
    updateUser.LastName = user.LastName ?? updateUser.LastName;        
}
```

**Solution 2:** using  `conditional (ternary)` operator

```
SetUpdateUserValue(User updateUser, User user)
{
 updateUser.FirstName = user.FirstName!=null?user.FirstName:updateUser.FirstName;
 updateUser.LastName = user.LastName!=null?user.LastName:updateUser.LastName;
}
```

Comment: This behaves differently: the original code does not modify updateUser if the respective user member is null.

Comment: @peterchen: yes, updated my answer. Thanks for yur valuable comment.

Comment: This code have doubles:  updateUser.FirstName = user.FirstName ?? updateUser.FirstName;
    updateUser.LastName = user.LastName ?? updateUser.LastName;

Comment: @zrabzdn: yes it has becaue if the value is `null` it shouldnot assign anything means it should reassign the same value what it has now. i don't think you can get much smaller than this :(

Comment: Agree with Sudhakar.  This is as good as can be reasonably expected.  Don't use reflection for this when writing production code.  Instead, encapsulate this behavior in a class.  Use good OO, not expensive and difficult to read language features.

Answer (score 0):

As is, the function is fine.

If you have long lists of these, you could consider

```
static void SetIfNotNull(ref string target, string source)
{
   if (source != null)
      target = source;
}



SetUpdateUserValue(User updateUser, User user)
{
    SetIfNotNull(ref updateUser.FirstName, user.FirstName != null);
    SetIfNotNull(ref updateUser.LastName,  user.LastName != null);
    ...
}
```

This would be a bit better for a long list, but still be prone to copy-and-paste errors.

Alternatively, you could use reflection to iterate the members (or a list of known members), if you are willing to take the performance hit.

Comment: How about one method for all object properties? SetIfNotNull(objectProperty1, objectProperty2);

Comment: @zrabzdn: That implementaiton would have the "many ifs" again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to copy properties from source object to destination object.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886/c-sharp-using-reflection-to-copy-base-class-properties) for your reference.

Comment: Reflection is not best practice

Comment: Sure.@zrabzdn Is there any better solution to collect the properties of object?