# C# Linq alternative for lodash omit function

Tags: c#, linq, lodash

Sample input:

```
// remove sensitive data    
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == '123').ToList()
      .Omit("PasswordHash", "PasswordSalt", "SecretDataAsInteger");
```

Output:

```
{
  FirstName: "...",
  LastName: "...",
  PasswordHash: "", // default value instead of real value
  PasswordSalt: "",
  SeretDataAsInteger: 0
}
```

Similar to:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#omit

Preferences:

- I prefer solutions without selecting a new object and setting each property except the ones i want to omit i.e.

`var user = ..Users.Select(x => new User {/* here I set each property */})`

since this lead to update all reference, in case I have updated the `User` model properties later

- Passing object in the omit function instead of properties name as string is also acceptable

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to the method `Omit` could be implemented?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think the omit method modifies anything, I think it's basically "give me all the objects without these specified properties", useful for excluding password fields or sensitive data I suppose.

Comment: @DavidG: It's not a matter of omitting the *objects*, but the *properties*, as far as I can tell... so yes, it could still be done as an equivalent to `Select`, but it's that rather than `Where`...

Comment: It sounds like you basically want something that will copy properties via reflection, but omit certain ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886 looks relevant.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, I agree, I misread that part. So it *is* a reasonable thing to do with LINQ. A short but complete example would certainly have made it all clearer, IMO... (Will remove the comment.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I deleted my comment, because after you edited yours, your comment was perfectly clear. No need to delete yours.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a class that I have created for you that should using a list of provided Property names should set them to be the default value of the Property type. Using your example:

```
// remove sensitive data    
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == '123').ToList()
  .OmitProperties("PasswordHash", "PasswordSalt", "SecretDataAsInteger");
```

Remember to include `System.Reflection`.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
        public static IEnumerable<T> OmitProperties<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, params string[] propertyNames) {
            PropertyInfo[] propertiesToOmit = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                .Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name))
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var item in enumerable) {
                foreach (var property in propertiesToOmit) {
                    property.SetValue(item, null);
                }

                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't write high level C# for a while, and I want to ask: Isn't using reflection in this way extremely slow? e.g, if I'd write something like this instead `db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == 123).Select(x => new User { Name = x.Name, Id = x.Id })` - (manually omitting), wouldn't that be faster? (Although not answering the answer...)

Comment: I would agree that manually omitting the Properties instead of using this would be quicker. However in creating a new instance of the `User` class every time arguably would take up more memory (in GC or object creation) and may cause it to run slower. Depends is the answer.

Comment: @LukeFisher Creating a new instance of the `User` class, or a new instance of an anonymous type, is cheap: it reduces the cost of the original `User` object, as that would become short-lived without any references to it. The GC is very good at getting rid of those. Certainly cheaper than using reflection for each individual user.

Comment: @hvd never wen't into .NET allocator's internals, but this sound plausible. Anyway, the fastest way would probably to manually loop over and set all needed properties, I guess.

Comment: Based on the question, I think they will require to use the Reflection approach to setting the Properties to be 'default'. I assumed that they were looking to keep the existing `User` for whatever purpose and just 'nullify' properties that they specify.

Comment: @LukeFisher, yes u r right, but maybe I am a little biased on my question since I am getting from a JS background, maybe in C# this is not the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the `User` class, you can add a constructor taking `User`. Make this constructor copy all the fields. You may trivially do so using reflection. If you implement this by dynamically generating a helper method that does the work you need, the helper method only needs to be generated once. Given this constructor, you can write

```
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == 123).AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => new User(x) {
    PasswordHash = "",
    PasswordSalt = "",
    SecretDataAsInteger = 0
  }).ToList();
```

This keeps it type-safe: you cannot accidentally omit properties that `User` doesn't have (say, you attempt to omit `PasswordSlat` rather than `PasswordSalt`), and you cannot accidentally omit properties by setting them to a value that the property type doesn't support (say, attempting to omit `SecretDataAsInteger` by setting it to `null`), and attempts to do so anyway will be flagged by the compiler rather than blowing up at runtime.

Comment: thanks for mentioning this, but in my situation I prefer to not create a ctor just for this.

Comment: There should be a whole new object not just a constructor if you are crossing a security boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that isn't Linq and actually updates the base objects. Might not be quite what you want, but it does the job:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ApplyToAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
    params Action<T>[] action)
{
    foreach (var element in sequence)
    {
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            omission(action);
        }
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

And instead of passing the string names of the properties, you pass in some actions that act on the input:

```
var redactedUsers = users.ApplyToAll(
    u => u.Password = "",
    u => u.Name = "Hello " + u.Name);
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning this, However in this case I prefer to name it `Apply` or something else instead of `Omit`

Comment: Actually you are right, a much better name would be that or perhaps `ApplyToAll`